# Use a modal ng-controller as a regular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a controller used by a modal view (with angularui). At some point I would like to use this controller with a custom view (not a modal one). So everything is fine except for the resolve variables (variables sent to the controller).

I call the modal like this:

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
        controller: 'modalCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            variable: function(){
                return myVar;
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I send variables from javascript (or html)?

Here is how I bootstrap my custom view (custom.html):

```
angular.element($(document.body)[0].children[0]).attr('ng-controller','modalCtrl');
angular.bootstrap( document.body, [ 'myApp' ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to define a service or a value with the same name of your resolve (`variable` in this case). Then Angular will find the dependency for you and inject it.

You may not want to always have this service/value defined. So you might define this service/value in a module, and then conditionally load that module when you bootstrap the app:

```
if (someCondition) {
  angular.module('use.me.conditionally', []).value('variables', 123);
  angular.element($(document.body)[0].children[0]).attr('ng-controller','modalCtrl');
  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp', 'use.me.conditionally']);
} else {
  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the `value()` or `service()` functions to declare injectable  objects that have many properties:

```
var foo = { property1: 'abc', property2: 456 };
angular.module('use.me.conditionally',[])
    .value('variablesAsAValue', foo)
    .service('variablesAsAService', function() { return foo; });
```

Note that you don't need both `value()` and `service()`, I'm just showing both approaches. `value()` is typically used for constant type of variables, and services are typically object/classes.

Comment: Thanks but how can I add multiple variables? Should I change the name of the value (use.me.conditionally) for each variable? Can I put them all in once or add them in a loop?

Comment: @ncohen I'll edit my answer, you can pass an object using either the `value()` or `service()` approach.

Comment: @ncohen Also don't worry too much about the module (in my example 'use.me.condtionally'), you don't really need an extra module. You could use your existing 'myApp' module just the same. I only suggested a separate module if you wanted to sometimes not use this modal controller and therefore wouldn't need the value/service.